# Proof that $\text{int}(X)\cup \text{int}(Y)\subset \text{int}(X\cup Y)$ but not always $\text{int}(X\cup Y)\subset \text{int}(X)\cup \text{int}(Y)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

I want to prove that 1. $\text{int}(X)\cup \text{int}(Y)\subset \text{int}(X\cup Y)$ but 2. it isn't always the case where $\text{int}(X\cup Y)\subset \text{int}(X)\cup \text{int}(Y)$.

The first part is done, although I think it seems less formal than it should. Did I forgot something?

The second part I did with a counterexample, showing that $\text{int}(X\cup Y)\not\subset \text{int}(X)\cup \text{int}(Y)$, but I would like to show the possibility of $\not\subset$ without the use of counterexample. How to do so? I think I wouldn't be able to arrive at a contradiction, since this would imply that would never be the case where $\text{int}(X\cup Y)\subset \text{int}(X)\cup \text{int}(Y)$, and this is not true.

*Edit:* both $X$ and $Y$ are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

1. $\text{int}(X)\cup \text{int}(Y)\subset \text{int}(X\cup Y)$

*Proof*. Let $x\in \text{int}(X)\cup \text{int}(Y) \implies x\in \text{int}(X)$ or $x\in \text{int}(Y)$.

For $x\in\text{int}(X)$, we know that there exists an $\varepsilon_X>0$ such that $x\in (x-\varepsilon_X,x+\varepsilon_X)\subset X$. The same can be said about $x\in \text{int}(Y)$, that is, we know that there exists an $\varepsilon_Y>0$ such that $x\in (x-\varepsilon_Y,x+\varepsilon_Y)\subset Y$.

Therefore $x\in (x-\varepsilon_X,x+\varepsilon_X)$ or $x\in (x-\varepsilon_Y,x+\varepsilon_Y)\implies x\in(x-\varepsilon_X,x+\varepsilon_X)\cup (x-\varepsilon_Y,x+\varepsilon_Y)$.

As $(x-\varepsilon_X,x+\varepsilon_X)\subset X$ and $(x-\varepsilon_Y,x+\varepsilon_Y)\subset Y$, then

$$x\in(x-\varepsilon_X,x+\varepsilon_X)\cup (x-\varepsilon_Y,x+\varepsilon_Y)\subset X\cup Y$$

By definition of interior, $x\in\text{int}(X\cup Y)$. $\blacksquare$

$\rule{10cm}{0.4pt}$

2. $\text{int}(X\cup Y)\not\subset \text{int}(X)\cup \text{int}(Y)$

For this, we define $X=\left[\alpha_X,\beta_X\right)\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $Y=\left[\beta_X,\beta_Y\right]\subset\mathbb{R}$.

We see that $X\cup Y = \left[\alpha_X,\beta_X\right)\cup \left[\alpha_X,\beta_Y\right] = \left[\alpha_X,\beta_Y\right]$. Therefore $\text{int}(X\cup Y)=\text{int}(\left[\alpha_X,\beta_Y\right])=\left(\alpha_X,\beta_Y\right)$.

As $\text{int}(X)= \text{int}(\left[\alpha_X,\beta_X\right))=\left(\alpha_X,\beta_X\right)$, and also $\text{int}(Y)= \text{int}(\left[\beta_X,\beta_Y\right])=(\beta_X,\beta_Y)$. We have that $\text{int}(X)\cup\text{int}(Y)=\left(\alpha_X,\beta_X\right)\cup \left(\beta_X,\beta_Y\right)$, that is, $\beta_X \not\in\text{int}(X)\cup\text{int}(Y)$.

Therefore $\text{int}(X)\cup\text{int}(Y)\subset \text{int}(X\cup Y)$ but $\text{int}(X\cup Y)\not\subset\text{int}(X)\cup\text{int}(Y)$ hence $\text{int}(X\cup Y)\neq \text{int}(X)\cup\text{int}(Y)$.

$\rule{10cm}{0.4pt}$

*Experiment*. Let $x\in\text{int}(X\cup Y)$. Let's follow the consequences and see where we arrive.

As $x\in\text{int}(X\cup Y)$ there exists and $\varepsilon>0$ such that $x\in (x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\subset X\cup Y$. We can't say that $x\in (x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\subset X$ neither that $x\in (x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\subset Y$, because for any $A\subset X\cup Y$, there may exist an $x\in A\subset X\cup Y$ such that $x\in X$ and $x\not\in Y$ and an $y\in A\subset X\cup Y$ such that $y\not\in X$ and $y\in Y$.

Any hint on how to proceed from here?

Comment: A concrete coutner example is $X = \mathbb{Q}$ and $Y = \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. They both have empty interior but their union is $\mathbb{R}$, which is open.

Comment: @DIdier_ A counterexample so obvious. Thanks.

Comment: An easier/more conceptual  way to prove the first inclusion is to note that $\mathrm{int}(X)\subseteq X\subseteq X\cup Y$. Since $\mathrm{int}(X\cup Y)$ is the largest open set contained in $X\cup Y$, this implies $\mathrm{int}(X)\subseteq \mathrm{int}(X\cup Y)$. Symmetrically with $\mathrm{int}(Y)$. Since $\mathrm{int}(X)$ and $\mathrm{int}(Y)$ are both contained in $\mathrm{int}(X\cup Y)$, so is their union. This arguments works in *any* topological space, and allows you to avoid mucking about with elements and open neighborhoods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your proof of the first part and your counterexample for the second part are fine. I am not sure what you mean by

> but I would like to show the possibility of $\not\subset$ without the use of counterexample. How to do so? I think I wouldn't be able to arrive at a contradiction, since this would imply that would never be the case where $\text{int}(X\cup Y)\subset \text{int}(X)\cup \text{int}(Y)$, and this is not true.

As you say, it is not true that there is never a containment (an easy example of equality would be to take both $X$ and $Y$ to be open - say $X=Y=\varnothing$).

Comment: I would like to arrive at this conclusion without the use of counterexamples. Suppose that $\text{int}(X\cup Y)\subset \text{int}(X)\cup \text{int}(Y)$. How can I arrive at the conditions for when this is true and when this is not? That's what I tried at the experiment.

Comment: @E.C.: So, you are trying to find conditions under which $\mathrm{int}(X\cup Y)$ will equal $\mathrm{int}(X)\cup\mathrm{int}(Y)$ (since the other inclusion will always hold) ?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Yes, but when I start with $x\in \text{int}(X\cup Y)$ I face a dead end, as for any sets $A,X,Y\subset\mathbb{R}$, we know that $A\subset X\lor A\subset Y \implies A\subset X\cup Y$, not the other way.

I know the counterexample is enough to say that not always $\text{int}(X\cup Y)\subset\text{int}(X)\cup \text{int}(Y)$, but I would like to follow an element of $\text{int}(X\cup Y)$ and see what paths it can take to reach inclusion (or not).

Comment: @E.C. I see, now I get it. I'm not sure there is any nice condition for this...

Comment: @Cronus Ok, thanks! I'm trying to follow Tao's advice and "ask myself dumb questions", even if I fail to arrive at someplace useful.

Comment: @E.C. That's a very good thing to do :-)