# a) Prove: for any $X,Y \subset \mathbb R$ we have $int(X) \cup int(Y) \subset int(X \cup Y)$...

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification, problem-solving

> a) Prove: for any $X,Y \subset \mathbb R$ we have $int(X) \cup int(Y) \subset int(X \cup Y)$.

> b) Give an example of sets for which $int(X) \cup int(Y) \ne  int(X \cup Y)$.

a) Let $x \in int A$ then exist $ \epsilon \gt 0$ such that $(x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon) \subset A$ then $(x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon) \subset A \cup B$ and $(x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon) \subset int(A \cup B)$ the same for $B$, so $intA \cup intB \subset int(A \cup B )$.

b) A=(0, 1] and B=[1, 2)

How is my answer?

Thanks.

Comment: Be careful to use inclusions and not "$\in$" with your intervals. The reasonings you make are true otherwise.

Comment: A [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3875545/proof-that-textintx-cup-textinty-subset-textintx-cup-y-but-not?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $A \subset B$ implies that $\mbox{int}(A) \subset \mbox{int}(B)$.

We know that
$$
X \subset X \cup Y
$$
which implies that
$$
\mbox{int}(X) \subset \mbox{int}(X \cup Y) \tag{1}
$$

We also know that
$$
Y \subset X \cup Y
$$
which implies that
$$
\mbox{int}(Y) \subset \mbox{int}(X \cup Y) \tag{2}
$$

From (1) and (2), we conclude that
$$
\mbox{int}(X) \cup \mbox{int}(Y) \subset \mbox{int}(X \cup Y) \tag{2}
$$

To show that the set inequality can be strict, we give the following standard example with $X = \mathbf{R}$, the usual topology.

Take $A = (0, 1]$ and $B = [1, 2)$. Then
$$
\mbox{int}(A) = (0, 1), \ \mbox{int}(B) = (1, 2)
$$

Hence,
$$
\mbox{int}(A) \cup \mbox{int}(B) = (0, 1) \cup (1, 2)
$$

But
$$
A \cup B = (0, 2)
$$
which is an open set in $\mathbf{R}$.

Hence,
$$
\mbox{int}(A \cup B) = (0, 2).
$$

For this example, we have
$$
\mbox{int}(A) \cup \mbox{int}(B) = (0, 1) \cup (1, 2) \neq 
\mbox{int}(A \cup B)
$$